# Problems with settings movie size using SWFLoader

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex3

I have the following problem:

When I embed an swf movie via HTML  tag, the movie has the given dimensions. Unfortunately, doing this with SWFLoader (setting height and width) does not work. The movie seems to have full-screen size.

EDIT:

Here is the code of SWFLoader (it gets scaled to 240x320 but the movie loaded is much bigger and does not fill the whole window):

```
<mx:SWFLoader  id="video" autoLoad="true" height="240" width="320" scaleContent="true" maintainAspectRatio="true" source="http://movie_address" />
```

Here is the working code of  tag:

```
<object width="320" height="240" ><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="movie" value="http://movie_address" /><embed src="http://movie_address" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="320" height="240"></embed></object>
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Also I suggest you should have a look at the documentation for it http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary

Answer (score 0):

Try by using scaleContent="true";

```
<s:SWFLoader id="loader1" source="@Embed(source='sample.swf')" x="100" y="100" 
                 width="200" height="200" scaleContent="true"/>
```

Comment: First of all, I cannot embed it - it must be loaded at runtime. Apart of this, scaleContent="true" does not work as intended. I need the movie to be 320x240. Currently it is bigger and it is scalled-down to the given size.

Comment: Try to set source and scaleContent property on complete event of SWFLoader. or share "http://movie_address".